# Как сделать три фото с текстом внутри по центру?

Tags: html, css

[image: Хочу сделать как на фото]

```css
.slider__section {
  height: 635px;
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
          <div class="slider__div">
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/1вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title"></h2>
                  <p class="slider__text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/2вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title"></h2>
                  <p class="slider__text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/3вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title"></h2>
                  <p class="slider__text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что фото, что текст внутри блоков - всё выравнивается с помощью *flex*. Просто задавать его необходимо не тем элементам, которые требуют выравнивания, а их предкам:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.slider__div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider__section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 30px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider__title {
  font: bold 16px/1em sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider__text {
  font: 12px/1em sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slider__div">
    <div class="slider__section" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg)">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="slider__">
          <h2 class="slider__title">Дизайн и строительство</h2>
          <p class="slider__text">Совокупность зданий и сооружений, создающих пространственную среду для жизни и деятельности человека</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__section" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg)">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="slider__">
          <h2 class="slider__title">Строительство и ремонт</h2>
          <p class="slider__text">Процесс их изменения, восстановления, улучшения, доведения до первоначальных характеристик</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__section" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg)">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="slider__">
          <h2 class="slider__title">Отделка интерьеров</h2>
          <p class="slider__text">Оформление поверхностей стен, установку напольного покрытия, украшение помещения мебельным гарнитуром</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```